# How to keep Flutter debugger alive even in background?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, debugging

How do you keep the debugger from dying when your app is put on background? Every time I change the active app and wait a few seconds without bringing it back, the debugger accuses `lost connection to the device`.
This is true either with a custom project or with a recently created project.

Comment: FYI - [Dart-Code issue #4274](https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/4274)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it happens because the device doesn't have enough ram to keep the debug app open, you can test my answer by using a device having large ram of 4GB or more

Comment: Probably right, i changed to a Mi A3 and the problem seems to stop. However, I have had this problem sometimes even with the Mi A3. Is there any way to be sure?

Comment: by comparing the remaining ram, before debugging and while debugging

Comment: This is a comment not an answer from next time please keep in mind your actions

Comment: My device has 256 GB RAM (that'a a "G"), and the peak memory usage of the app is 128 MB (that's an "M"), so I don't think memory is related to my situation.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use an simulator for android or ios. Then you can tab out and tap in. Then it still has the app open even for longer times.